# Very high CPU usage with simple Java Game Loop

Tags: java, cpu

I've been learning the principles of Game design and have made this game loop in Java with the help of many tutorials. All it does right now is render a grass tile on to a JFrame:

```
public class Game extends JPanel implements Runnable {

String title;
int height;
int width;

boolean ps;

private int ticks;  
private JPanel p;
private BufferStrategy bs;
private Graphics g;
private boolean running = false;
private Thread thread;  
private Frame frame;
private KeyHandler keyHandler;

public Game(String title, int width, int height){
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    this.title = title;
    keyHandler = new KeyHandler();
}

private void init() {
    TileHandler.init();
    frame = new Frame(title, height, width);
    frame.getFrame().addKeyListener(keyHandler);
}

private void tick() {
    // KeyHandler.tick();

    // updates game logic       
}

private void render() {
    render(g);      
}

private void render (Graphics g) {  
    bs = frame.getCanvas().getBufferStrategy();
    if(bs == null){
        frame.getCanvas().createBufferStrategy(3);
        return;
    }
    g = bs.getDrawGraphics();
    g.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);   

    g.drawImage(TileHandler.grass, keyHandler.getPlayerX(), 
    keyHandler.getPlayerY(), null);

    bs.show();
    g.dispose();
}

@Override
public void run() {

    int x = 4;
    init();
    int fps = 60;  // target
    double tickTime = 1000000000 / fps; // time per 1 frame
    double delta = 0;   
    long timer = 0;

    long startTime = System.nanoTime();
    long endTime;

    while (x == 4) {
        endTime = System.nanoTime();
        delta += (endTime - startTime) / tickTime;
        timer += endTime - startTime;
        startTime = endTime;

        if (delta >= 1) {
            ticks++;
            render();
            delta--;
        }
        if(timer >= 1000000000){
            ticks = 0;
            timer = 0;
        }
    }
}

public int getTicks() {
    return ticks;
}

public synchronized void startThread() {
    // Start the thread
    if (!running) {             // if not already 

        running, you can begin
        running = true;
        thread = new Thread(this); //Run THIS class on a 

        new thread
        thread.start();
    }
    else {  // safety measure
        return;
    }
}

public void stopThread() {
    if (!running) {
        return;
    }
    running = false;
    try {
        thread.join(); //Method stops the thread
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

}

It works well enough and I can get it running at a steady 60 FPS, the only problem is it eats up so much CPU. On average it uses about 50% CPU and slows down the rest of my computer  - Minecraft uses about the same on my laptop! I know for a fact that the problem lies in the game loop in the code above.

So I'm just trying to understand what is causing this to happen. I did try to use a profiler but I still couldn't work out what was causing the problem.

Comment: The loop is constantly running to see if it needs to call render(). This is called polling and is usually a bad idea. Try using a timer to call render() instead.

Comment: Also I would advise you to look into JavaFX, since it uses hardware acceleration it is much more suited for game developement. It also comes with classes like [AnimationTimer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/animation/AnimationTimer.html) and [Timeline](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/animation/Timeline.html) that make gameloop management quite easy.

Answer (score 2):

Ok to give the most simple answer: Your loop is running as fast as the CPU can handle it. I assume you have a CPU with two cores, so the main loop thread is using every bit of computing power it can get to run through the loop as fast as possible and is thus blocking one of your two cores (50%).

One solution is to calculate how long each iteration takes and sleep for an amount of time until the next iteration can start. Here is a pseudo code:

```
while(running) {
    long startTime = getTime();

    update();
    render();

    long endTime = getTime();
    long elapsedTime = endTime - startTime;
    Thread.sleep(TARGET_FRAME_TIME - elapsedTime); //sleep to yield unneeded CPU usage
}
```

Also you will not get very good performance out of swing, if you are not using a OpenGL library like LWJGL or JOGL. I don't know what your game will be, but 60fps is probably the upper bound for swing.

I advise you to learn JavaFX for games since it uses hardware acceleration for rendering and can handle 120fps+ for relatively complex applications. It also provides [Timeline](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/animation/Timeline.html) and [AnimationTimer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/animation/AnimationTimer.html) classes for game loop design.

Comment: +1, however Swing still blocks sometimes the rendering process, with [`newt`](http://jogamp.org/jogl/doc/NEWT-Overview.html) this doesn't happen anymore

Comment: Thanks for the advice everyone, I understand what's going on now a lot better than before. Seems like a 2D game library is the way forward then!

Comment: If you want to stay with the standard library look at JavaFX. It is perfect for 2D Games, when you don't want to go 3rd party. (I may be a little fanboy)